# How to add split between duplicate value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have SQL Server table that have duplicated value in field and need to split by slash character. All field start with alphabetical char end with 'M' char

For example:

```
     X123X123M
     Y1515Y1515M
```

and need to convert to:

```
     X123/X123M
     Y1515/Y1515M
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably many ways to skin this cat, assuming you're always looking for the same initial character repeated within the string, the following uses *stuff* to insert a slash at the appropriate location:

```
with t as (
    select 'X123X123M' val union all
    select 'Y1515Y1515M'
)
select val, Stuff(val,v,0,'/')
from t
cross apply(values(CharIndex(Left(val,1),val,2)))v(v)
```

Comment: A design pattern I'm not familiar with.  flagging for review and potential future use!  thanks @stu .  Hmmm breaks if the same intial character is used multiple times I get it now.

Comment: Well no doubt it might need tweaking if your data varies from that in your sample, but it could be taken into account.